# Efficient way to broadcast/iterate over dictionary values

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am trying use dictionary values in a calculation such as this:

```
mydict = dict(zip(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
                  [1, 2, 3]))
print(mydict)

newvals = (mydict.values() + 3) ** 2
print(newvals)
```

```
{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_values' and 'int'
```

Or if I do,

```py
import numpy as np
newvals = (np.array(mydict.values()) + 3) ** 2
print(newvals)
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_values' and 'int'
```

It appears I have to convert the dictionary values to a list first, or iterate with a list comprehension.

```py
newvals = (np.array(list(mydict.values())) + 3) ** 2
print(newvals)
```

```
[16 25 36]
```

Or I can do

```py
newvals = np.array([(val + 3) ** 2 for val in mydict.values()])
print(newvals)
```

```
[16 25 36]
```

Is there an easier or more efficient way to do this? 
Or is there an inbuilt method for dictionaries that I can employ so that I don't have to use a list comprehension or for loop?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to do this without loops you either have to use parallel processing with a shared memory data structure (such as is available in the multiprocessing library in the standard library), or a library like numpy which is written in c and Fortran and is specifically designed for this task. Single threaded processing using the vanilla Python dictionary or list is great for many tasks, but it's the wrong way for fast parallel computing without loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we talk about avoiding loops in `numpy`, what we actually mean is avoiding Python level loops.  We still have to loop through the array elements, but we do it in fast compiled code.  That code only works on `numpy` `ndarrays`.  Furthermore, loops through arrays are worse than loops though lists.

If we start with lists, we have to first convert it to `ndarray`, e.g. `arr = np.array([1,2,3])`.  That array conversion takes time, enough so that often it is faster to do a list comprehension.

`numpy` does not have any code to work directly with Python `dicts`.  `values()` makes a generator-like object.  `np.array(...)` requires a list like object:

```
In [140]: np.array(list(mydict.values()))                                                      
Out[140]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [141]: (np.array(list(mydict.values())) +3)**2                                              
Out[141]: array([16, 25, 36])
```

`fromiter` can work from the `values` object:

```
In [142]: np.fromiter(mydict.values(), int)                                                    
Out[142]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

`np.fromiter` may be faster than `np.array`, but I won't guarantee it.

I suspect that the list comprehension is faster, especially for this small example:

```
In [143]: [(x+3)**2 for x in mydict.values()]                                                  
Out[143]: [16, 25, 36]
```

We could do some time testing, but for this small sample it probably won't be that useful.

Dictionaries are useful for a lot of things, but fast numeric calculations is not one them.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it for you.

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
    mydict[key] = (value + 3) ** 2
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is desirable to not use for loops or list comprehensions. May be there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for([key,value] in mydict.items()){

      mydict[key] = (value + 3 ) ** 2

      console.log(mydict[key]);

     }
```

In this way you are accesing e. g 1 touching 'key1'. 1 + 3 ** 2.                                   first value from key 1: 16